# ExpandableListView with Drag and Drop of List Items in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Im looking for the ExpandableListView which has got Drag and Drop of ListItems in Android, or else is there any good tutorial or examples ,where can i learn to implement drag and drop for ExpanadableListView . i found some good tutorials for implementing drag and drop for ListView.
but i haven't found any good link for ExpandableListView . please help me on this.

Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure you can implement Drag and Drop in List View.. Here is the Samples for Drag and Drop in List View.. [Drag and Drop Sample](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html).. Download Zip file from this part in the page -(You can find the project here.)

Comment: Hi venkatesh , sorry for the late reply..i already used that example .but now i want to implement Drag and drop for ExpandableListView. please tell me is there any example for it.

Comment: user593424 - Did you find any example of Drag and Drop for ExpandableListView? I'm interested too. Thanks

Comment: I am searching for same. Found a expandable list with drag drop functionality. But it dont works on s5

Answer (score 3):

I modified the drag and drop listview and updated it to drag and drop expandable listview, download the code from [here](https://github.com/sreekumarsh/android/tree/master/Drag%20N%20Drop)

Comment: The above link is broken. Can you please provide a valid link.

Comment: Link to download the project is not working(Page Not Found Error).

Comment: @SreekumarSH, I check your sample, but there is one problem like if list if big, you can only drag drop visible items. If you pick visible item and want to put at end of list, you can't. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: @SreekumarSH how can we drag and drop group?

Comment: @NikPatel Goto DragNDropListView.java, in the ontouchevent, you can see that only child group are dragged, if(getPackedPositionType(packagedPosition) == 1)  
you can remove this and add your code to do the group drag and drop

Comment: I have added the code to scroll the list view while dragging please check.

Comment: @Sreekumar.  There is a bug on your code. It is not working on some devices. I tested for samsung s5 it is not responding for longpress drag. Please i am looking forward for this solution. I dont want to switch to another way. Please do it asap.