# Expandable ListView with Drag and Drop Item

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, expandablelistview

I want to reordering item in expandable listview. is it possible?
If possible than please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Everything is possible...... what do u need from our side? did u tried anything?

Comment: No. Can you please provide me example? Its better for me. Thanks

Comment: please refer the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454743/expandablelistview-with-drag-and-drop-of-list-items-in-android

Comment: @SreekumarSH Hi, u did good job but with some limitations....and the main drawback is when u drag an item and reached at bottom the expandable list is not scrolling.

for eg. 3 groups are there, each group has 10-10 items, drag 1st item from first group, when u reach at bottom the, even there are so many items.....expandable list doesn't scroll....

Comment: and if anyone know the answer....please share

Comment: fixed it, please check