# Drag and drop expandable RecyclerView's list item by position with child node

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview

I am not able to move child list item when I move my parent list item. Also need to move child item when position of parent item will change by user in Android Studio.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class myAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<TitleParentViewHolder, TitleChildViewHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    private final OnStartDragListener mDragStartListener;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    TitleParent titleParent;
    ArrayList<TitleParent> titleParent1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<TitleChild> TitleChild1 = new ArrayList<>();

    public myAdapter(Context context, List<ParentObject> parentItemList, OnStartDragListener dragListner) {
        super(context, parentItemList);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mDragStartListener = dragListner;
    }

    @Override
    public TitleParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_parent, viewGroup, false);
        return new TitleParentViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public TitleChildViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_child, viewGroup, false);
        return new TitleChildViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindParentViewHolder(final TitleParentViewHolder titleParentViewHolder, final int i, Object o) {
        titleParent = (TitleParent) o;
        titleParent1.add(titleParent);
        for (int j = 0; j < titleParent1.size(); j++) {
            titleParentViewHolder._textView.setText(titleParent1.get(j).getTitle());
        }
        titleParentViewHolder._textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "PostionParent: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(final TitleChildViewHolder titleChildViewHolder, final int i, Object o) {
        TitleChild titleChild = (TitleChild) o;
        TitleChild1.add(titleChild);

        for (int k = 0; k < TitleChild1.size(); k++) {
            titleChildViewHolder.option1.setText(TitleChild1.get(k).getOption1());
            titleChildViewHolder.option2.setText(TitleChild1.get(k).getOption2());
        }

        titleChildViewHolder.option1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(titleChildViewHolder);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        titleChildViewHolder.option2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(titleChildViewHolder);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        titleChildViewHolder.option1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "PostionChiled: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {

        if (fromPosition < titleParent1.size() && toPosition < titleParent1.size()) {
            if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
                for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                    Collections.swap(titleParent1, i, i + 1);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                    Collections.swap(titleParent1, i, i - 1);

                }
            }
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        titleParent1.remove(position);
        if (TitleChild1.size() > 0) {
            TitleChild1.remove(position);
        }
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnStartDragListener {

    int i = 1;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ItemTouchHelper mItemTouchHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        ((myAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this, initDate(), this);
        adapter.setCustomParentAnimationViewId(R.id.tvButton);
        adapter.setParentClickableViewAnimationDefaultDuration();
        adapter.setParentAndIconExpandOnClick(true);

        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new EditItemTouchHelperCallback(adapter);
        mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private List<ParentObject> initDate() {
        TitleCreator titleCreator = TitleCreator.get(this);
        List<TitleParent> title = titleCreator.getAll();
        List<ParentObject> parentObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        for (TitleParent titleParent : title) {
            i = i+1;
            List<Object> childlist = new ArrayList<>();
            childlist.add(new TitleChild("Add: " + i, "Send"));
            titleParent.setChildObjectList(childlist);
            parentObjects.add(titleParent);
        }
        return parentObjects;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStartDrag(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        mItemTouchHelper.startDrag(viewHolder);
    }
}

EditItemTouchHelperCallback.java

public class EditItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    private final myAdapter mAdapter;

    public EditItemTouchHelperCallback(myAdapter adapter) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                          RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

What I want is move child list item when I move my parent list item and move child item when position of parent item will change by user

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454743/expandablelistview-with-drag-and-drop-of-list-items-in-android

Comment: but i m not able to find solution on this link

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.